# Whats the maximum number of sheets that an excel workbook can handle?

Tags: c#, excel

**Scope**

I am currently developing automated excel reports using C# and some frameworks just like  [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/).

Due to a really specific request of how data should be viewed within this report, i am being forced to do something that may push excel to the edge.

**Numbers**

At the moment, I am creating one different Sheet for each different combination of 3 Segments, 11 Months (jan-dec + all) and 4 "Phases" (you don't have to know what that is, but its a category attribute).

At this point im currently sitting on top of exactly 132 different worksheets (each one being a combination of the attributes i just cited)

**Then, it goes Kaboom !**

Our costumer loved the way we handled the problem, because they couldn't solve it themselves. In fact, they loved it so much that they decided to add yet another attribute/category for the combination. They also want to see the same views per "Load Date" (date in which the file was loaded into the database). After doing a quick math we can estimate that this change will sky-rocket the number of Excel Sheets within the same workbook to roughly 1600.

**Go Big or Go Home**

We are scared of trying it because we don't think excel will be able to handle this Sheet Overload.

Will it ?

Comment: If you look at the [specs](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP005199291.aspx) it has : `Sheets in a workbook Limited by available memory (default is 3 sheets`

Comment: As @Habib said, it seems you won't really be limited by the number of sheets, but by available memory, but it seems like you're creating a solution that isn't scalable and have a customer with changing requests... When that happens, you often have to reconsider how to tackle the problem... Maybe a background Database rather than so many sheets?? Overall, what happens in 4 months time when they say they want 2 extra attributes added?? - Just my 2 cents....

Comment: @JohnBustos I know mate, i know. We have considered connecting this report directly to redshift, but its harder than that. The way they want to visualize the data is so "unique" that excels pivot table wont be enough. Thanks for the 2 cents mate

Comment: Yup, sometimes you just have those kind of clients that need it JUST the way they need it... Good luck, man!!!

Comment: With 132 tabs (let alone 1600), how do users navigate from one view to another?  There are no shortcuts to allow someone to move, say 35 tabs forward.

Comment: @ExactaBox (I agree with your answer below) but a user can right click on the sheet navigation arrows at the left of the sheet list, and get a listbox (or scrolling Menu depending on the version) with the names of all the sheets.

Comment: @Spevy good point, but usability is still a significant issue with 100+ tabs to select from

Comment: @MarcelloGrechiLins, I know what we've said up top, but if I were you, I'd maybe try posting your exact situation and the solution you came up with as a separate question and see if anyone has a more logical solution than your current one... Worst case scenario, you find that your solution makes the most sense and you help another person facing something similar see how you worked through the problem....

Comment: Regarding to navigation, we`ve implemented a smart button system. So clicking the button actually navigates to another sheet, but to the user, they are simply applying filters (each button is a filter, hence, the combination of the buttons lead to different sheets)

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you would need to be using the 64-bit version of Excel to handle this, which may not be practical.

Excel has the advantage of holding all the data, formulas and formatting of results in memory, which is fast when loaded but uses a lot of memory and can be slow to load.

Having many sheets does not significantly increase the Excel memory load unless you have formula links between the sheets: memory load is usually a factor of the number of cells containing data, formatting and formulas.

Maybe Excel PowerPivot might provide some help: lots of power and scalability there way beyond ordinary pivots.

Comment: Definitely +1 for the PowerPivot suggestion, I was thinking the same, but didn't know enough about the problem set to know if it makes sense... DEFINITELY worht a mention, though!!

Answer (score 2):

With all due respect for you initial solution, and seeing that the customer "loved" it, I can see why your initial thought process is just to expand and make it bigger... but in reality, wouldn't it be FAR more efficient to have one sheet with the entirety of the source data (or connection to it), and a "presentation" sheet where the user could enter the individual parameters (in your case, the current 3 attributes plus the new Load Date), and the results would be filtered/selected/processed on the single tab?  You could use sliders, scrollers, spinners, radio buttons, etc to ease users going through multiple attribute combinations -- you could have a single button representing each of the most popular attribute combinations -- the UI options are WAY more flexible than having 132 to 1600 tabs, where the only way to switch between 2 views is to go up/down the list of tabs.

tl;dr -- I think you should seriously consider re-evaluating your solution to the client request.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @rkhb To be logically consistent, you should first critique the body of the question.  If the only thing he actually wants to know is the max number of worksheets, why does he go on to tell us that he currently has 132 sheets, that he might have 1600 sheets, that he is using C#, etc.  All of that diverts attention from the title question.  However, I'm assuming he put that info in there to add context, and to expand the scope of the discussion -- and that is what I am replying to.

Answer (score 1):

The number of sheets is only limited by the available memory (and you're likely using Excel 32-bit since the x64 version is frowned upon, so the available memory will be limited by that also). From working with Excel Addins, I've seen Excel struggle once memory consumption goes over 1.2GB.

Given that, the limitation in your case  will more likely depend on the size of the data in the sheets, and any pivotcaches you create in the background. 1600 sheets should work providing each dataset isn't a massive size.

That being said, I'd question whether Excel is a viable solution to this problem; users love it as they are familiar with it, but something like Tableau may give them a better visualization of the data and is far more scalable.

Comment: We are currently using Redshift to handle the background data, since it is massive in both size and variety. They are not flexible about excel, because they have to distribute it internaly to other areas, so excel is a must for them.